# Spring-JPA(Hibernate): AssertionFailure: null id in `xxxx` entry(don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I need do a data migration from a legacy system, and there are 20,000+ records totally[all the data will be provided by csv file], due to some technical reasons, I must use JPA/Hibernate to import those data into your new system currently used.

When I do the importing, always encountered a transaction problem like following:

The database is **MS SQL Server 2005**

> org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in `xxxx` entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

And I tried following things:

1. Using a nested exception to importing the separate record.
2. Split the data to some pieces small csv file
3. Call `entityManager.flush()` manually and add `Thread.sleep(10000)` to sleep 10ms
4. Call `titityManager.flush` every 20 records and sleep 5ms

But unfortunately, nothing seems to help. Please help.

Thanks for reading. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that JPA mappings are correct?

Comment: Yes,the JPA mapping are correct.

Comment: Have you checked that the date being migrated is valid?

Comment: Yes, it's valid, actually if the data is not too large, like 20 records, can be migrated to the db correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If mappings are correct, probably is a wrong import code like described in [org.hibernate.AssertionFailure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477054/org-hibernate-assertionfailure).
Also you can look about [Hibernate batch processing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) best pratices and [Stateless session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession).
Last option can be move to [spring-batch](http://www.springsource.org/spring-batch)